# Install Tensorflow with SYCL support

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, opencl, nvidia

I am tring to use gdb to trace Tensorflow operation kernel implementation with Eigen SYCL support.
However, when I try to install the `.whl` package, some error messages about `fglrx` pop up.

#### Error message

```
Compiling /tmp/pip-1vfYDJ-build/tensorflow-1.0.1.data/purelib/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py ...
  File "/tmp/pip-1vfYDJ-build/tensorflow-1.0.1.data/purelib/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py", line 1
    Error: Fail to load fglrx kernel module!
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ....
```

#### Configuration

- CPU: Intel Core i7-4790
- GPU: GeForce GT 630/PCIe/SSE2
- OS:  ubuntu 15.04
- Driver: [Nvidia binary driver nvidia-352](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rlUk.png)

#### Command

Here are commands I used according to the tutorial.

https://www.codeplay.com/portal/03-30-17-setting-up-tensorflow-with-opencl-using-sycl

- configuration

  ```
  Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/local/bin/python]: 
  Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation [Default is -march=native]: 
  Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? (Linux only) [Y/n] 
  jemalloc enabled on Linux
  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] 
  No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] 
  No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] 
  No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
  Found possible Python library paths: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]
  Using python library path: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] y
  OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
  Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] 
  No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
  Please specify which C++ compiler should be used as the host C++ compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/clang++-3.6]: 
  Please specify which C compiler should be used as the host C compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/clang-3.6]:
  ```
- bazel build:

> bazel build -c dbg --config=sycl 
>       //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

- build pip package:

> bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package

- install pip package

> sudo pip install:
>   /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Please help me in resolving the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (currently) use SYCL with TensorFlow on Intel GPUs. However, it is coming soon. There are a few fixes you will need and then it will work correctly. You will need to wait for a new Intel OpenCL GPU driver and then for a few compatibility commits to TensorFlow before it will work on Intel GPU. You may also want to wait a little longer for some performance improvements, because we have been focusing more on correctness, first, with performance coming a little later.

Comment: Is there any forecast of when SYCL/TensorFlow/Intel GPU will be available, even in Beta form? Any link you can provide to a place to keep an eye on progress?

Answer (score 1):

The SYCL variant currently requires a platform that supports SPIR or SPIRV, like Intel or AMD. NVIDIA platform does not currently support neither.

Comment: Can I use the intel integrated graphic card to run Tensorflow with SYCL support ? If yes, what should I do ?

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Codeplay in ComputeCpp, one of the SYCL implementations.
ComputeCpp works with Intel GPU platforms, so you should be able to run it. There are some Intel GPU driver issues that cause some failures when passing structs to kernels, and that might affect some of the TF kernels (not sure). In any case, those issues will probably be fixed sooner rather than later by Intel.